# Ajax call to c# function not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to use Ajax to call a C# function but the call is not working.The script shows the hello message but does not show the success/error message.What am i doing wrong

Java script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnsave1').click(function () {
            alert("hello");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "LeaveSurrender.aspx/apply",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function () {
                    alert('Successfully Saved');
                    // window.location.href = "ClubCreation.aspx";
                },
                Error: function () {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });

        });

    });
```

C# Method

```
 protected void apply()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("hi");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
   [WebMethod]//write [WebMethod]
   public static string apply()//method must be "pulic static" if it is in aspx page
   {
        return "Hi";
    }


 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "LeaveSurrender.aspx/apply",
                dataType: "json",
                data:'{}',
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                    // window.location.href = "ClubCreation.aspx";
                },
                Error: function () {
                    alert('error');
                }
        });
```

Comment: The way he is calling, the method neither have to be public nor have to be webmethod.

Comment: I forgot to add the public static,now works.But the MessageBox does not show and  the objects which i refer in this method shows up an error saying that an object reference is required for non static fied,.....

Answer (score 2):

Few things you need to fix here. **First:**  **there's no MessageBox in webforms.**  change the apply() method to return string:

```
protected string apply()
{
    return "hi!";
}
```

**Second:** Use `'#btnsave1'` to `'#<%= btnsave1.ClientID %>'` to get server generated id for button and also catch the string returned by apply() method. Your script should look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%= btnsave1.ClientID %>').click(function () {
            alert("hello");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "LeaveSurrender.aspx/apply",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    // window.location.href = "ClubCreation.aspx";
                },
                Error: function () {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });

        });

    });
</script>
```

**Third:** Make sure you have referenced jquery in the head of your page:

```
<head runat="server">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
```